Can I isolate the effect of each independent variable by using multiple linear regression?
I conducted the multiple linear regression with dependent variable Y and independent variables(predictors) X1 and X2 in python.
They are all time series data and I made reconstructed Y time series with the result of MLR.
reconstructed Y = b1 * X1 + b2 * X2 + residuals
Then, can I isolate the effect of each independent variable by just excluding the other one? like, Y' = b1 * X1. (The coefficient values are from MLR using X1 and X2 together.)
Is it reasonable? I want to see the effect of X1 or X2 one by one.

If you regress on X1 and then on both X1 and X2 and the coefficient of X1 doesn't change, then you have separate effects. Or X2 first, and so on. In general there aren't separate effects to be identified because X1 and X2 are likely to be correlated with each other. So the goal isn't a valid and achievable goal. There should be duplicates of this question somewhere. I will post if I find some.

What does 'I made reconstructed Y time series with the result of MLR." mean? Doing MLR on time series is often problematic. How did you account for time?

In multiple linear regression, the coefficients ( b1 ) and ( b2 ) represent the effect of ( X1 ) and ( X2 ) on ( Y ), controlling for the other variable. This means ( b1 ) is the effect of ( X1 ) on ( Y ) when ( X2 ) is held constant, and vice versa. If you want to see the effect of ( X1 ) or ( X2 ) one by one, you can't simply exclude the other variable and use the same coefficient. The coefficients are derived considering the presence of both variables. Excluding one would change the model and potentially the coefficients.
Marginal effects measure the change in the dependent variable ( Y ) for a one-unit change in an independent variable ( X ), holding all other variables constant. They provide a way to interpret the coefficients of your regression model in terms of their direct impact on ( Y ). In the context of your multiple linear regression model, the marginal effect of ( X1 ) on ( Y ) is given by the coefficient ( b1 ), and the marginal effect of ( X2 ) on ( Y ) is given by the coefficient ( b2 ). These coefficients already account for the presence of the other variable in the model.

+1 for clearly distinguishing the multiple regression model from the univariate regressions: failure to make that distinction appears to be at the root of a great many questions we get about multiple regression generally.  Welcome to CV, George.

I often quote your 1953 and 1976 papers.

Thanks, Nick. I do too.
